# Solve: $\tan(2\theta-36^\circ) = \sqrt{8}$

Tags: trigonometry

$\tan(2\theta-36^\circ) = \sqrt{8}$ in degrees.

I tried making $\sqrt{3}$ into $60$ degrees, and then the answer was $47$ degrees but I don't think that is right.

Comment: It seems that some very clever answers were based on the original problem statement. Try updating the second sentence (referencing $\sqrt{3}$, $60$ degrees, and $47$ degrees), to reflect the new problem statement as it seems that this is becoming a pentagon problem, and not one based on an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 2):

[image: The special angle triangle!]

If you let $2\theta-34 = \beta$

Then we know: $tan(\beta)=\sqrt3= \frac{opposite}{adjacent}$

And from the attached diagram we see the angle should be: $\beta=60 \implies \theta=47$

Comment: This is incorrect. $\theta=32$ is *not* a solution of OP's equation.

Comment: Yes, now quite correct. Nice diagram -- how did you generate it?

Comment: Credit goes to Google's image search.

Comment: Haha! Clever! The underlying triangle is indeed probably extremely commonly illustrated. That's a neat way of thinking about it. +1.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First solve $\tan x =\sqrt{3}$ for $x$, then solve $x=2\theta -34$ for $\theta$ (using the value for $x$ you found from the first equation).

And your answer is correct. There are also other solutions, since the first equation I wrote has multiple solutions (the function is periodic).

Comment: The question says theta is real numbers of degrees, does that change anything?

Comment: No, just that when you solve the first equation, you will get values of $x$ that are degrees, not radians. It is implicit that $x$ is a number of degrees since that's how you stated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tangent has period $\pi$ and is one-to-one within each period. Thus, we know that
$$
2\theta-34^\circ\equiv60^\circ\pmod{180^\circ}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\theta\equiv47^\circ\pmod{90^\circ}
$$